# Possible to listen for Video end and editing url with javascript?

Tags: google-chrome, php, html, javascript, css

So, i want a Autoplay-like script, that listens for a video that ends, and when it ends, it rises the last Number from the Url one up like x = x + 1 or x+= 1. Im not quite in to Javascript, more into python. any ideas? (maby it could be done with css, php, html or javascript)
I have tried to do this via an extension named Tampermonkey, which lets you implement script to your browser. But at the point to make the script, i got stuck because i didn't knew how to even make an event listener that triggers when the video has stopped.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Why is the Question always the reason, only because it does not show everything clearly, i think the feature i want to have is clear. I didnt put any links or research, because im open to every solution. and only becasue i want one thing, im not going to learn a whole new Programming language.

Comment: Super User is not a 'please write it for me' scripting service. We are here to help if you get stuck with a specific issue, which you need to describe clearly & show your research.

Comment: Ok. Im sorry about that, in this case i cant write it for me because i dont know the laguage. Can you tell me approximately how long it takes to learn basic Javascript? ill come back then.